# Adding Link for Button Action

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I recently started a new site with Apostrophe CMS, and one of the features in the project will be extending apostrophe-events to have a list of "registered" users who are associated with each event. I was able to add a new joinByArray column to the apostrophe-events module, and it works correctly when editing events.

Now, I'm trying to add a Register button to the apostrophe-events-pages module, so that users can register for the event from each event's page. I currently have a working API endpoint available, which I created using this code:

(In file lib/modules/apostrophe-events-pages/index.js)

```
module.exports = {
    construct: function(self, options) {
        self.route('get', 'register', function(req, res) {
            // Validate things with the launder module
            var name = self.apos.launder.string(req.body.name);
            // Deliver a JSON response
            return res.send({ status: 'ok', moreInfo: 'something' });
        });
    }
};
```

That endpoint works as expected, but I'm stuck on adding a button with a link to the correct action on the front end. I created a button that looks correct in the show.html overwrite that I created, with the following code:

(In lib/modules/apostrophe-events-pages/views/show.html)

```
{{ buttons.minor('Register for Field Trip', { action: 'register' }) }}
```

I'm not sure how I can add a link to the register action. I tried adding this code to the same index.js file as above:

(In lib/modules/apostrophe-events-pages/index.js)

```
self.registerEvent = function() {
    var res;
    self.api('register', {}, function(result) {
        res = results;
    });
};

var superBeforeShow = self.beforeShow;
self.beforeShow = function(callback) {
    self.link('register', self.registerEvent);
    return superBeforeShow(callback);
};
```

But when I access the event page, an error happens that says self.link is not a function. Should I be putting the link code elsewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the lead architect of Apostrophe at P'unk Avenue.

First, you're having difficulty because you're trying to call frontend javascript APIs like `link` from the `index.js` file of your module, which is back-end node.js code.

You will need to push an `always.js` javascript file to the browser. You can call this in your module's `index.js`:

```
self.pushAsset('script', 'always', { when: 'always' });
```

Then populate your module's `public/js/always.js` file with your frontend code.

Second, the `self.link` code you're probably looking at is really only intended for something that is "in context," for instance to a particular dialog box. You are looking to bind to any click on a button with a particular data attribute. For that, you could write:

```
apos.ui.link('register', 'event', function($el, _id) { ... }
```

In your always.js, and this code will respond to anything with an action named `register-event`:

```
{{ buttons.minor('Register for Field Trip', { action: 'register-event' }) }}
```

But this is just a convenient way to write a jQuery delegated event handler. You could also just write:

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-register-event]', function() { ... })
```

You should wrap your always.js code in a DOM Ready function:

```
$(function() { ... })
```

As for calling `self.api`, that is pretty convenient, and you can look into subclassing `apostrophe-context` to get access to it, but you can also just build the URL yourself and invoke our `jsonCall` jQuery plugin from your `always.js`:

```
$.jsonCall('/modules/your-module-name/register',
  { ... data ... },
  function(result) { ... }
);
```

Please check out the tutorial [building a contact form](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/forms.html), which includes material on how to push an `always.js` file from the `public/js` folder of your module as an asset and so on.

That tutorial also demonstrates the technique of using a custom apostrophe widget type to provide a home for your frontend code, which I generally recommend. It gives you access to `self.api` and so on.