# Pieces manage options in a separate menu

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm managing some articles as pieces on my Apostrophe and would like to give my users the option of creating and deleting pieces from the page that lists all pieces. For usability reasons, I'd preferred to have these in a more visible and easy to access way.

At the moment to manage a piece, users need to go to **Admin Bar > Articles** so that they can manage all Article related tasks from the **Manage popup**.

Is there anyway I can achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `apostrophe-pieces-submit-widgets` module provides a basis for creating new pieces from outside the admin context .. If you use it as a base you could build something like what you're describing.

https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-pieces-submit-widgets

Answer (score 0):

Following on this, what I did was to (1) create a **route** inside my `moduleName-pages/index.js` that will basically give me access to the Manager modal and (2) created an `always.js` to add a button and call **self.api**.

There's another way to do this according to this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751390/adding-link-for-button-action), but also based my solution on how the apostrophe-pieces module creates this functionality as follows:

```
apos.ui.link('manage', 'placement-guide', function () {
      self.manage();
    });

self.manage = function() {
  return self.api('manager-modal', {}, function(data) { ... }
```